# How to scroll through a section vertically while keeping the section clipped to the screen?

Tags: user-interface, animation, next.js, frontend, framer-motion

So I am trying to build a landing page using NextJS and Framer Motion. I want to build a section that has 3 images to be scrolled one after the other.
When you enter the section completely the section must stick to the page and the three images should geet scrolled one after the other.
When you are finished scrolling through the last image you continue with normal flow.

The entire scroll of the section must be part of the normal scroll flow only and not use the overflow property.

> For reference kindly check out https://chroniclehq.com/ with the section that  has title **"CREATE AT THE SPEED OF THOUGHT".** Kindly view it in desktop.

I guess this problem is similar to the horizontal scroll effect with vertical scrolling where the section gets sticked to the page until we completely scroll through the section and then we keep on continuing with the normal flow. Here we only want the horizontal scroll effect to be changed with the vertical scroll effect.

If possible use Framer Motion.

Any help or reference to any blog or pen is appreciated.

I can't think of anything on how to tackle this problem.